# Different graph after equation simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I guess this is some basic question, but I cannot see what I'm doing wrong. This is the equation I have:

$$\frac{1}{ax+1}+\frac{1}{bx+1}-c=0$$

and I want to convert it to quadratic equation like so:

$$\frac{(bx+1)+(ax+1)}{(ax+1)(bx+1)}-c=0$$
$$\frac{bx+ax+2}{abx^2+ax+bx+1}-c=0$$
then we multiply both sides with $abx^2+ax+bx+1$ and retain restriction that $ax\neq-1, bx\neq-1$
$$bx+ax+2-c(abx^2+ax+bx+1)=0; ax\neq-1, bx\neq-1$$
$$bx+ax+2-cabx^2-cax-cbx-c=0; ax\neq-1, bx\neq-1$$
$$x^2(-cab)+x(b+a-ca-cb)-c+2=0; ax\neq-1, bx\neq-1$$

Now, if I draw 2 graphs for these 2 functions by $x$ it seems it is different. How is this the case?

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gxnkiglyyv

Comment: In the first expression, for some value of $x$, $1/(ax + 1)$ is not defined. Similarly for $1/(bx+1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that you get a quadratic equation, so there are two roots. One of them is precisely the point you're avoiding (eg, ax = -1)

Comment: OK, so basically on that graph left side that is visible is actually ax=-1 or bx=-1

Comment: This is I guess OK now. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ma0ccrqoxk

Comment: Perfect! That does it...